# MultiSearch with JqGrid and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'd like to use the multisearch facility from JqGrid within an ASP.NET MVC application. When setting up the grid you set a URL that becomes the action method on a controller. But how do I find out what the parameters should be defined for the action method. I've seen in another post that working out what the parameters should be is the hardest bit, but they didn't explain how you do it.

Can anyone advise please.

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you (theoretically, anyway) have *no idea* what the keys will be, I'd just parse the Request.Query collection.

Comment: Thanks Craig, FYI the query string collection contains the following:

page, rows, _search, sidx, sord, nd, filters

As far as search/filtering goes the interesting items are _search which is true or false indicating whether the user has initiated a search/filter and filters which appears to be a JSON object containing the search/filter criteria that needs to be parsed to filter the data.

Comment: OK, it's changed since the last version, then. The filters used to be separate arguments. In that case you probably can/should use named arguments.

Comment: Yes I will, have you any idea what the nd parameter is, it appears to be an integer but what does it indicate?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need an answer, but I'd give this a read:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetMVCandJqGrid.aspx